# How safe is JavaScript number type for money operations?

Tags: javascript, currency

Is it safe to use JavaScript number type (64-bit double precision) for money operations? We plan to develop a software for small businesses and amounts are usually less than 100.000$, but I think numbers may be much larger because we use local currencies and for example, 1$ = 6.5 Chinese yuan.

I know that there may be lost of precision, but how bad is it in the real world?

I also suggest that we can skip problems like

```
0.2 + 0.1 = 0.30000000000000004
```

because after truncating the number using local currency settings it would be the same eg `$0.30`

Some people also recommend to scale values by multiplying them by 100, but I'm not sure this will work in every situation, because I suggest there may be currencies with more than 2 digits after point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589293/currency-operations-with-javascript

Comment: could you please mark first answered answer as answer?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use Integers when you are dealing with money. [Floating point arithmetic is broken](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and is unreliable so its better to use fixed type for money calculations.

However there are [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) library which is often used to deal with calculations related to money.

Here is a good reference and related thread on the same: [Precise Financial Calculation in JavaScript. What Are the Gotchas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876536/precise-financial-calculation-in-javascript-what-are-the-gotchas)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is using the special libraries

like the [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js)

For example:

```
0.3 - 0.1                           // 0.19999999999999998  
x = new BigNumber(0.3)
x.minus(0.1)                        // "0.2"
x                                   // "0.3"
```